# aiogram ошибка при установке!python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

скачал библиотеку aiogram, при помощи `pip install aiogram`
Но при запуске выводит это.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\samael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiogram\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import bot
  File "C:\Users\samael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "C:\Users\samael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .. import types
  File "C:\Users\samael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import base
  File "C:\Users\samael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\base.py", line 1
    from __future__ import annotations
    ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А какой Python вы используете? Скорее всего, вам нужно обновить версию.

В [PEP-563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7) написано, что это все заехало в 3.7 Python.

Comment: Вы правы! Моя ошибка. Уже исправил!